# How to send request from IPv6 in socks in request in Python?

Tags: python, ipv6, ipv4, socks

I use IPv4 for socks in my project, but I need to connect with IPv6 socks in my project.

**IPv6: (for example)**

ip: 1.1.1.1

port: 1080

username: username

password: password

**My code:**

```
import socks
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "{}".format(proxy_row['ip']), proxy_row['port'], True, 'username', 'password')
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
url = 'http://website.domain'
response = f.get(url, timeout=10)
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. I am guessing (you didn't specify) that you are using [this library](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks/blob/master/socks.py#L231) which hints that it works with IPv6, but without an error (or even an explanation), I can't tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald Hi, After run code `f.get...` show this error: `raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error))
SOCKS5Error: 0x05: Connection refused`

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks), `0x05 - Connection refused - The target server has actively refused the connection (the requested port is closed).`

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald My English is not so good please give me more guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the [Github page](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks), your server is refusing connection, meaning that the service you are trying to connect to is not hosted at that IPv6 address.

> 0x05 - Connection refused - The target server has actively refused the connection (the requested port is closed).

I would try using `nmap` or `ping` to check if the service is live at the IP in question ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/1135757/scanning-in-ipv6/1135761)).